# Can I use Jinja2 `map` filter in an Ansible play to get values from an array of objects?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a playbook for creating some EC2 instances and then doing some stuff with them. The relevant pieces are approximately like:

```
- name: create ec2 instances
  ec2:
    id: '{{ item.name }}'
    instance_type: '{{ item.type }}'
  register: ec2
  with_items: '{{ my_instance_defs }}'
- name: wait for SSH
  wait_for:
    host: '{{ item.instances[0].private_ip }}'
    port: 22
  with_items: '{{ ec2.results }}'
```

This works as intended, but I am not especially happy with the `item.instances[0].private_ip` expression, partly because it shows really large objects in the play summary. I would love to have the `with_items` part just be an array of IP addresses, rather than an array of objects with arrays of objects inside them. In Python, I would just do something like:

```
ips = [r['instances'][0]['private_ip'] for r in ec2['results']]
```

And then I would use `with_items: '{{ ips }}'` in the second task.

Is there a way I can do the same thing using a J2 filter in the YAML of the play? Seems like http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#extracting-values-from-containers might be helpful, but I think that presupposes I have an array of keys/indices/whatever.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[map](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/templates/#jinja-filters.map) filter it your friend here.

Something like this:

```
with_items: "{{ ec2.results | map(attribute='instances') | map('first') | map(attribute='private_ip') | list }}"
```

*The code above is not tested.*
You may want to try with `debug` first and gradually add `map`s to get required result.
Don't forget to put `| list` at the end to make your map readable.

Comment: Works like a charm! I didn't quite understand how `map` was supposed to work until I read your example and the docs at http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#builtin-filters. Also +1 for the `list` advice.

Comment: Since I am using the array of IPs in multiple places, I decided to use `set_fact: ec2_ips={{ ec2.results | map(attribute="instances") | map("first") | map(attribute="private_ip") | list }}`.

Answer (score 0):

My example is pulled from my playbook removing a autoscaling ecs cluster. I modified the above answer to get mine working.

```
- name: get list of instances in ASG
  ec2_instance_facts:
    filters:
      "tag:aws:autoscaling:groupName": "{{item.name}}-{{stack}}-scalinggroup"
  register: asg_host_list

- name: list ecs info
  debug:
    msg: "{{asg_host_list}}"

- name: get just hosts id's
  set_fact:
    hostlist: "{{ asg_host_list.instances | map(attribute='instance_id') | list }}"
```

For my use hostlist can be fed directly into ecs_instance since it takes a list of instance ids to process.

So, this is tested and works.